# Is it ok to say "something I will have come to learn later in the course"?

Tags: past-tense, perfect-aspect, future-in-past, will-future, perfect-infinitive

I have written

> It lacks exact references to the book, something about argumentative analysis I **will have come to learn** later in the course.

I wonder if this is correct and what this tense would be called.

Perhaps it would be called “future past future perfect”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/future/future-perfect-simple-i-will-have-worked-eight-hours) it is future perfect simple, and is entirely acceptable.

The reason for this is that future perfect simple is constructed

> will/shall + have + the -ed form of the verb

which corresponds to

> [I] will have come [to learn]

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you mean with the sentence but it took me some effort. My choice would be:

- "It lacks exact references to the book, something about argumentative analysis **I would come to learn** later in the course."

This tense is called a **conditional perfect** and is described as "something that might have happened in the past but had not happened at that point".

Answer (score 0):

This is just the **fu­ture per­fect con­struc­tion**, a valid grammatical construction in English. However, given the amount of context you have supplied (none), how you are trying to use it here is not what a native speaker would normally choose. You should use a much simpler construction, because except in exotic circumstances, we certainly would do so.

From
[Wi­ki­pe­dia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_perfect#English):

> In English, the fu­ture per­fect con­struc­tion con­sists of a
> fu­ture con­struc­tion such as the aux­il­iary verb *will* (or
> *shall*) or the *go­ing-to* fu­ture and the per­fect in­fini­tive
> of the main verb (which con­sists of the in­fini­tive of the
> aux­il­iary verb have and the past par­tici­ple of the main verb).

There is no spe­cial name, nor need there be, just be­cause you have
rephrased *will have **learned*** into *will have **come to learn***. The im­por­tant thing is that at face value it does not make sense to
use this con­struc­tion here, be­cause the tem­po­ral mean­ing is
not clear in your sen­tence:

> It lacks ex­act ref­er­ences to the book, some­thing about
> ar­gu­men­ta­tive anal­y­sis I will have come to learn later in
> the course.

To see why, we must look at what that means. The con­struc­tion (*to*) *come to* + in­fini­tive has two re­lated
uses per the [OED’s sense 30 for *come*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/36824):

> - a. To be brought in the course of time or events to the ac­tion de­noted by the verb; to get to be, do, or have some­thing.
> - b. To reach (grad­u­ally or even­tu­ally) the point of un­der­stand­ing or know­ing some­thing; to grow to feel or think some­thing over time.

I pre­sume you are us­ing *come to* in the sense of “even­tu­ally”:

- come to learn > even­tu­ally learn

or in the per­fect,

- have come to learn > have even­tu­ally learned

So we can read your pro­posed sen­tence this way:

> It lacks ex­act ref­er­ences to the book, some­thing about
> ar­gu­men­ta­tive anal­y­sis I will have even­tu­ally learned
> later in the course.

Your use of the per­fect as­pect does not quite fit here. This
works a bit bet­ter:

> It lacks ex­act ref­er­ences to the book, some­thing about
> ar­gu­men­ta­tive anal­y­sis I will even­tu­ally learn later
> in the course.

But that still doesn't sit to­gether quite right.  You can fix this by adding
*when* or *once*

> It lacks ex­act ref­er­ences to the book, some­thing I will
> even­tu­ally learn about later in the course when we study
> ar­gu­men­ta­tive anal­y­sis.

If back­shifted for nar­ra­tion, *once* may read bet­ter than *when*
does:

> It lacked ex­act ref­er­ences to the book, some­thing I would
> even­tu­ally learn about later in the course once we stud­ied
> ar­gu­men­ta­tive anal­y­sis.

Some writ­ers might put that last verb in the per­fect as well:

> It lacked ex­act ref­er­ences to the book, some­thing I would
> even­tu­ally learn about later in the course once we had stud­ied
> ar­gu­men­ta­tive anal­y­sis.

In casual speech you could also say:

> It lacked ex­act ref­er­ences to the book, some­thing I’d
> even­tu­ally learn about later in the course once we got around to study­ing
> ar­gu­men­ta­tive anal­y­sis.

Just as *to come to* + in­fini­tive is a pe­riphrastic
con­struc­tion that lacks any par­tic­u­lar name, so too does the
*to get around to* + pro­gres­sive con­struc­tion sim­i­larly lack
any spe­cial name. English has no end of such con­struc­tions, so it
re­ally is not worth try­ing to in­vent dis­tinct ter­mi­nol­ogy
nam­ing each of them.

#### Technical note on “tense”

This is a pe­riphrastic con­struc­tion built an­a­lyt­i­cally by
chain­ing to­gether sep­a­rate words, not a mor­pho­log­i­cal
in­flec­tion wherein a sin­gle word al­ters its form to
in­di­cate the time, the way we see with present-tense *get*
in­flect­ing to past tense *got* or with present-tense *call*
in­flect­ing to past tense *called*.

So be­cause there re­ally aren’t any fi­nite verbs here, strictly
speak­ing there is there­fore no “tense” in the tech­ni­cal way that word is nor­mally used  in de­scrib­ing [syn­thetic lan­guages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_language).

(In other senses, *will* and *would* cor­re­spond to a pair of
present and past forms for the same verb, but these are modals, not
fi­nite verbs.)